# How to type new Map([['1', ()=>{}], [2, ()=>{}]]) ? I try to Map<string|number, () => void>, but it throw ts error No overload matches

Tags: typescript, dictionary, union

```js
const a: Map<string | number, () => void> = new Map([
  [
    2,
    () => {
      console.log('a');
    },
  ],
  [
    '2',
    () => {
      console.log('a');
    },
  ],
]);
```

throw following error
TS2322: Type 'Map<number | (() => void), number | (() => void)>' is not assignable to type 'Map<string | number, () => void>'.   Type 'number | (() => void)' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.     Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.       Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'number'.

try to use union type Map<NumberOrString, () => void>, throw the same error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inferred type of the array, which is:

```
((number | (() => void))[] | (string | (() => void))[])[]
```

If you type the array as an array of tuples, the Map infers it's own type correctly ([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwQLhgbWgglmA5jAHxjAFcBbAIwFMEAaGACgEoYBeAPhgDcQsATALpoBbdAFgAUDHFTpMAEy1Jcxiw4wA3spUxQkEABsqAOgMhcDAORxLTANzbpAXyWyBr6WkcxL8yx7lmNk4tWRU9CEMTMwtrWwcwmBdtd0kBBMkI2DhRMCoAdxgAWTgABwZEBHsgA)):

```
const arr: [string | number, () => void][] = [
  [
    2,
    () => {
      console.log('a');
    },
  ],
  [
    '2',
    () => {
      console.log('a');
    },
  ],
];

const a = new Map(arr);
```

Comment: Relevant GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37527

Answer (score 0):

```
const a = new Map<string | number, () => void>([
  [
    2,
    () => {
      console.log('a');
    },
  ],
  [
    '2',
    () => {
      console.log('a');
    },
  ],
]);
```

It fails to infer the type, just help it a bit

Comment: Relevant GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37527